# #sql Find Actors who have acted in all coen movies

Tags: sql, rdbms

Answer should be McDormand
here is the movie table
[image: movies t]

here is the acts table
[image]

Comment: Per the comment on the answer what makes you think it's only McDormand? Cage is obviously one too for Raising Arizon so if this is a homework question it sounds like either the question or solution are wrong.

Comment: you can check the table there are two titles Fargo and Raising arizona which was directed by Coen and in acts table cage  has worked only in one movie while McDormand has worked in all so answer is McDormand

Comment: I'd missed the "all" in your title but it's worth adding what database engine you're using, Fahmi's answer looks fairly right to me but might not work with some databases.

Comment: yeah its correct i am doing it in oracle

Comment: Its not working in oracle tho

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the below - **[DEMO](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=534960c753a11083ce9f5290b701045b)** Here

```
SELECT a.actor
FROM movies m
    INNER JOIN actors a ON a.title = m.title
WHERE m.director = 'Coen'
group by a.actor
having count(*)=(select count(distinct title) from movies where director = 'Coen')
```

Comment: no data found showing

Comment: @RaviSingh, check here - https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=534960c753a11083ce9f5290b701045b